# How to remove index.php from Ipaddress URL?

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter

How to remove index.php from my url. My domain is not parked i have a problem to redirect page.It shows 404. I'm using codeigniter.

My display URL :

http://example.com/index.php/crypto/dashboard

I need like this :

http://example.com/crypto/dashboard

My code is :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Hi Anonymous, My problem is htaccess not working in ipaddress URL. Normal domain name url its working.Kindly advise me.

Comment: Looks fine. For which URL it is not working?

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index.php|images|css|js|robots.txt|favicon.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Your are missing ./ before index.php

Answer (score 0):

```
**Uncomment** mod_rewrite.so in httpd.conf
#LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
to 
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so

**create** .htaccess file on root app folder
with my example script
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /hrd/

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>  

**codeigniter**   config.php

set --- $config['index_page'] = 'index.php';

to --- $config['index_page'] = '';
```